# spark group and serialize list

Tags: apache-spark, serialization

I am looking to aggregate a Dataset (id, score, field1, field2, field3) by id and include the other columns, sorted by score into some sort of list/column so that they can be serialized into the following object.

`collect_set` takes only one column, so I'm not sure how to the all the fields into a column short of concat. I also need to limit the list column to the top 3 Tests. The resulting Dataset would look something like: `Integer id, Array(List)`.

```
id, [[score, field1, field2, field3], [score, field1, field2, field3], [score, field1, field2, field3]]

class Student {
    private int id;
    private List<Test> tests;
}

class Test {
    private int score;
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
}
```

For example:

```
id1,99,"just","some","text"
id1,95,"just","more","text"
id1,75,"still","more","text"
id1,88,"yet","more","text"
```

would result in:

```
id1,[[99,"just","some","text"], [95,"just","more","text"], [88,"yet","more","text"]]
```

This is different than previously asked questions in that it involves a sort and limiting the output, which is why the answer required aWindow function and answers to other questions did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage `Window` functions and `struct`:

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(
    Seq((1, 99, "a"), (1, 95, "b"), (1, 75, "c"), (1, 88, "d"))
  ).toDF("id", "score", "field")

df.show
+---+-----+-----+
| id|score|field|
+---+-----+-----+
|  1|   99|    a|
|  1|   95|    b|
|  1|   75|    c|
|  1|   88|    d|
+---+-----+-----+

val w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy($"score".desc)

val res = df.withColumn("row", row_number().over(w))
  .filter($"row" <= 3)
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(collect_list(struct("score", "field")).as("data"))

res.show(false)
+---+------------------------+                                                  
|id |data                    |
+---+------------------------+
|1  |[[99,a], [95,b], [88,d]]|
+---+------------------------+

res.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- score: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- field: string (nullable = true)
```

**NOTE**: Verify that `collect_list` maintains the order by `score`. If not (and if you care about ordering), you will need to create an `udf` that resort your list `data`

Docs:

- [row_number](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#row_number())
- [rank](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#rank()) (compare to row_number)
- [dense_rank](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#dense_rank()) (compare to rank)
- [struct](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.html)
- [Window](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html)